# How do I display a Configurable Product even when its' Simple Products are "Out of stock"?

Tags: products

I'm trying to display the configurable product even if its' associated simple products are sold out. When the simple products are all "Out of Stock", the configurable item disappears. I'd like it to remain "Visible" even if it's not orderable.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the display out of stock  product option in admin panel.

> admin > System > Configuration > Inventory > Stock Options > Display Out of Stock Products